# Why is Primary Key faster than Index?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a MySQL 5.5 table that looks like this;

```
CREATE TABLE `date_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `module_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`report_date`,`module_id`,`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It only has one PK, and no Indexes. Running a simple SELECT query;

```
select count(*) from date_test
where report_date between'2014-09-01' and '2014-09-15'
```

This takes **1.1 seconds**, returns 809,349 records.

Now, I add an Index on report_date, to try and speed this up;

```
ALTER TABLE `date_test`
ADD INDEX `report_date` (`report_date` ASC);
```

My select count(*) query now takes **2.6 seconds** to run. My question; how did adding this field as an Index impact the query performance?

Adding EXPLAIN;

```
With Index and PK (2.6 seconds) 
id            1   
select_type   SIMPLE    
table         date_test   
type          range   
possible_keys report_date   
key           report_date   
key_len       8   
ref     
rows          792170    
Extra         Using where; Using index    

With PK only, no Index (1.1 seconds)  
id            1   
select_type   SIMPLE    
table         date_test   
type          index   
possible_keys     
key           PRIMARY   
key_len       1048    
ref     
rows          1584341   
Extra         Using where; Using index    

With no Index or PK (1.4 seconds)     
id            1   
select_type   SIMPLE    
table         date_test   
type          ALL   
possible_keys     
key     
key_len     
ref     
rows          1652883   
Extra         Using where
```

Comment: Why did you stick so many columns into PK?

Comment: Try checking for _select count(*) from date_test
where report_date between'2014-09-01 00:00:00' and '2014-09-15 23:59:59'_ to ensure there is no conversion from date to datetime involved.

Comment: Adding the time to the query doesn't seem to improve performance, it must implicitly add '00:00:00' to the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the result from the `EXPLAIN <YOUR_QUERY>`. My guess is (not enough info to be certain) that MySQL is now using the index and is incorrectly guessing that using the index will be faster.

If there are many rows covered by the index than it's can be faster to simply do a table scan instead. An index adds some overhead while querying so if the `between` covers more than 80% (completely arbitrary, but you get the idea) of the rows in the table, the table scan can be faster.

Look at the output from this query to get an idea:

```
SELECT report_date between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-15', COUNT(*) FROM date_Test
GROUP BY report_date between '2014-09-01' and '2014-09-15'
```

Comment: I've added my EXPLAIN for each of the three queries. I think your observation about MySQL picking the 'wrong' index applies here.